# int array to returning to previous record

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a standard form which displays information based on a partID. The form has a subform showing ancillaries of the part where on double click will take you to that part number (code snippet below). var_lastPartID is a global long variable which records the current ID so upon pressing a return button will take you back to the previous record. However, as this can only store 1 value at a time I imagine the best way would to be to store an array of long/int whereby upon the double click the current ID is stored. When you click return it will take the last value added and take you to that record then delete that record, so that the next time you click return it will take you to the next record. However, my experience with VBA is very limited and I have not used them before. Please could someone explain the syntax of how I could achieve this?

```
Private Sub childPart_DblClick(Cancel As Integer)
    var_lastPartID = Forms![Part]![part_ID].Value
    Forms("Part").Recordset.FindFirst ("part_ID = " & childPart)
End Sub
```

Comment: Not sure I understand your question. I think you're asking to store X number of previous records (using the part ID) so the user can go back to (potentially up to X) previous records. Is this correct?  If so, then I'd suggest using a [`Collections.Stack` object](https://analystcave.com/vba-stack-using-vba-stack-excel/) to create a LIFO stack and use that to track your list of previous part IDs.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so you have a parent form, and then a sub form.

You click on a row in the sub form. You want the parent form to JUMP to this record. But as you may well do this several times, then you want on the main form some kind of “back” or “previous” button. When you click on this back button, then you want the previous ID that you jumped to occur.

Ok, the way to drive this and have a next/previous set of buttons that traverse the records that you looked at, worked on, and clicked on?

Ok, in the main form, at the code module level, create a pointer, and a collection, and a routine like this:

```
  Option Compare Database
  Option Explicit

  Dim intListPosition     As Integer
  Dim colRecords          As New Collection


  Public Sub AddAndJump(MyID As Long)

     ' add this new ID to the list
     intListPosition = intListPosition + 1

     colRecords.Add MyID, CStr(intListPosition)

     ' now jump (move) to this record
     Me.Recordset.FindFirst "ID = " & MyID

  End Sub


  Public Sub BackOne()

     ' call this code from your back buttion
     ' go to previous record

     If intListPosition > 1 Then
        intListPosition = intListPosition - 1
        Me.Recordset.FindFirst "ID = " & colRecords.Item(CStr(intListPosition))
     End If

  End Sub


  Public Sub ForwardOne()
     'call this code from your forward buttion
     If intListPosition < colRecords.Count Then
        intListPosition = intListPosition + 1
        Me.Recordset.FindFirst "ID = " & colRecords.Item(CStr(intListPosition))
     End If

  End Sub

  Private Sub cmdBack_Click()

     BackOne

  End Sub

  Private Sub cmdNext_Click()

     ForwardOne

  End Sub
```

So the above goes in the main form.

In my "sample" code, I used ID, you have to change that to part_id

Now, you button code in the sub form is going to be "similar" to what you have, but you can now use this:

```
Call Me.Parent.AddAndJump(Me.ID)
```

So, the above will now allow a next/back button on the top form, as you click away and select the items from the lower form (the sub form), then the list of "id" will be built up, and the buttons for next/prev will work.